# How to make my navbar-brand responsive on low resolution?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar-brand goes down when I resize my browser or either I use it on my low resolution mobile device.

### [Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patootiegarcia/8TxEc/)

My NavBar Code:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default" id="page">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="img/feueac-logo.png" style="position:absolute; width:30px; height:35px; top:7px; left:5px;" /><span style="padding-left:25px; padding-top:0px;" class="navbar-brand" >FEU - EAC  E - Project System</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="client.php">Client Application</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Login <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn_red"><a href="#">Faculty</a></li>
                    <li id="modal_trigger2" href="#modal2" class="btn_red"><a href="#">Student</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li id="modal_trigger3" href="#modal3" class="btn_red"><a href="#">Guest</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <p style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:4px;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" placeholder="Search" style="width:300px; height:30px;">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Here's some [examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5bAt.jpg):

#### Good:

[image: screnshot good]

#### Bad:

[image: Screenshot bad]

#### Worse:

[image: Screenshot worse]

Comment: we don't mind if you show us your code or create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net Questions with links only wan't help anyone if the links get lost one day

Comment: Sure, I'll make it fast thanks.

Comment: Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patootiegarcia/8TxEc/

Comment: Well, if you have a long title and a small screen, it's going to wrap. The only thing you can do is use media queries to make the text smaller, or re-structure that bar so when it does wrap it doesn't look as bad.

Comment: Patricia, good start on the fiddle, but you should read their [tutorial](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html) to clean it up a little. The fiddle markup should only contain what you would traditionally put in the body tag.  Everything else belongs somewhere else.  Also, you should attach bootstrap as an external resources instead of inlining the css so it's easier to tell which styles you've applied and which ones are provided by the library.  Here's a [bootstrap template in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck using [**FitText**](http://fittextjs.com/), a jQuery plugin that fits text to it's parent element.

From their website:

> FitText makes font-sizes flexible. Use this plugin on your fluid or responsive layout to achieve scalable headlines that fill the width of a parent element.

Not exactly an "answer" (which there may be none of for this question), but a decent solution.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 Good suggestion, even if it has been a long day! :)